# 08:10:58.779 ServerScriptService.TimerScript:17: attempt to concatenate Instance with string - Server - TimerScript:17?

Tags: roblox

Im trying to make it so that it prints out the topplayer's name but it output prints the error on the title.

Heres the code:

```
local highest = 0
local mostvote = 0

while true do
wait(10)
local TopPlayer
local TopCash = 0

for i, plr in ipairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetChildren()) do
    local kills = plr.leaderstats.Kills.Value
    if kills >= TopCash then
        TopPlayer = plr
        TopCash = kills
    end
end

print(TopPlayer.." Got the most kills so "..TopPlayer.Team.." wins!")

for i, plr in ipairs(game:GetService("Players"):GetChildren()) do
    local kills = plr.leaderstats.Kills.Value
    kills.Value = 0
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(TopPlayer.." Got the most kills so "..TopPlayer.Team.." wins!")
```

The error tells you what's happening : you've got an Instance of something and you're trying to add a string to it, and it doesn't know what to do with it.
`TopPlayer` is a [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) instance, and you probably want to print out their name. So instead of using the Player instance directly, you should probably use their Name or their DisplayName in the message. Similarly, `TopPlayer.Team` is a [Team](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Team) instance, and you should probably print its Name as well.

```
print(TopPlayer.Name .." got the most kills so " .. TopPlayer.Team.Name .. " wins!")
```

Comment: it worked! thank you!